# Extending Threadpool Executor with BeforeExecute method not working properly for threads more than the pool size

Tags: java, multithreading

I am creating a multi threaded programming with ThreadPoolExecutor. I want to interrupt a thread if it is taking too much time to complete the task. So i am overriding beforeExecute method. It works good for the specified number of threads. Example if i am defining number of threads as 5, then five threads are working fine. But for the rest of the tasks, it creates new threads but all are failing saying sleep interrupted.

Request your help to fix this issue.

Here is the working code. If there is any other best approach, please post.

```
package com.ms.mt;

import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TimedExecutorService2 extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    long timeout;

    public TimedExecutorService2(int numThreads, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {
        super(numThreads, numThreads, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1000));
        this.timeout = unit.toMillis(timeout);
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeExecute(Thread thread, Runnable runnable) {
        Thread interruptionThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Wait until timeout and interrupt this thread
                    Thread.sleep(timeout);
                    thread.interrupt();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        interruptionThread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numThreads = 4, timeout = 5;
        ThreadPoolExecutor timedExecutor = new TimedExecutorService2(numThreads, timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            timedExecutor.execute(new Business(i));
        }
        timedExecutor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.ms.mt;

public class Business implements Runnable {

    private int i;

    public Business(int i){
        this.i =i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

---

Output:

```
pool-1-thread-1  
0

pool-1-thread-3  
2

pool-1-thread-4  
3

pool-1-thread-2  
1

java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.ms.mt.Business.run(Business.java:15)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.ms.mt.Business.run(Business.java:15)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Updated Main method for Andrew

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        final TimeoutExecutorService executor = new TimeoutExecutorService(6);
        final List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            futures.add(executor.submit(new Business(i), 4000));
        }

        for (final Future<?> future : futures) {
            future.get();
        }

        executor.workExecutor.shutdownNow();
        executor.timeoutExecutor.shutdownNow();
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the output?

Comment: I have added output. Thanks.

Comment: I would do two things: print the ID along with the exception type to be clear about which thread is bombing. But also place a breakpoint inside the catch blocks.

Comment: To properly implement this you need to keep track of the time a thread has been working it does not have to be in the before execute method struclty

Comment: You need a reaper thread that makes sure no work takes longer than the TTL

Comment: You can be draconian killing the offending thread on the spot or use give it one more go before termination. If this works I will post it as an answer

Comment: I tried adding thread name in catch. It is actually reusing the threads. I could not get "You need a reaper thread that makes sure no work takes longer than the TTL". Is there a simple way to kill a thread which is taking more than a specified time to complete a task in ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: What you are asking is how to implement a Time To Live policy. You  need an starting time per thread. The place to get it is before executing. But the enforcement is different, I would have another thread that keeps track that no thread exceeds the TTL since starting time of its current task thus reaping the offenders

Comment: I am new to Multithreading. Could you please give me an example if possible? My requirement is , 1) I am using ThreadPoolExecutor with 10 threads. 2) If any of the thread is taking more than 15 mins, i have to kill that thread and drop that task. 3) And thread pool will create new or reuse the thread for remaining tasks.  I am unable to do this with ThreadPoolExecutor. So i am trying by extending the ThreadPoolExecutor class. Could you please help?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: If you want to get started and post what you have later with the input you got here, I can help then. Not before

Comment: Nope. Not for homework. Stuck with this functionality in real time

Comment: give it a go then post. The TTLs have to live in a list so the reaper always checks the oldest first

Comment: I deleted my answer. The reaper thread ends up being starved outside the debugger so it does not execute. Maybe a custom thread pool not extending from TPE will do the trick. I may get around to play with this

Answer (score 1):

I've found that it's generally more productive to deal with Futures, rather than individual Threads. This allows you to cancel the *Runnable*, rather than worrying about which thread is doing which work at what time.

```
class TimeoutExecutorService {
    final ExecutorService workExecutor;
    final ScheduledExecutorService timeoutExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    public TimeoutExecutorService(final int numThreads) {
        this.workExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
    }

    final Future<?> submit(final Runnable runnable, final long timeoutMillis) {
        // use an atomic reference to allow code inside a runnable to refer to its own future
        final AtomicReference<Future<?>> futureReference = new AtomicReference<>();

        futureReference.set(workExecutor.submit(() -> {
            // schedule a different thread to cancel this one after a certain amount of time
            final Future<?> cancelFuture = timeoutExecutor.schedule(() -> {
                futureReference.get().cancel(true);
            }, timeoutMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            try {
                // do the thing 
                runnable.run();
            } finally {
                // if the runnable completes before the cancelFuture interrupts this thread, 
                // prevent the cancelFuture from running
                cancelFuture.cancel(true);
            }
        }));

        return futureReference.get();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        final TimeoutExecutorService executor = new TimeoutExecutorService(4);
        final List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            futures.add(executor.submit(new Business(i), 5000);
        }
        for (final Future<?> future : futures) {
            future.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If i use future, it is not spanning the number of threads at a time. It is running and by one.

Comment: As long as you don't call `get` or `join` on the futures before all of the work has been submitted, it should use all of the threads in the pool. (See update.)

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks. i could see one issue. The job is never ending. It completes its task but not ending the process.

Comment: After adding shutdown statements for both thread pool, it is getting terminated after completion. But in case of failure case, i am unable to terminate the process. Added updated main method and remaining code is same.

Comment: I would put each `future.get()` inside a try/catch block, so that one future completing exceptionally does not prevent you from waiting until each other future completes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your timeout thread interrupts the worker thread whether it finished its task on time or not. As worker threads in `ThreadPoolExecutor` are reused, the timeout thread may be interrupting one of the next tasks running on the worker thread.

***Edit***

The solution proved to be quite a bit more complex than I had anticipated.

However I think I've got it.

First I introduced a `PriorityBlockingQueue`, so I can have only one thread that will cancel all timed out tasks, instead of having an extra thread per task.

I made an internal class `TimedOutRunnable` that holds the timeout time (vs. `System.nanoTime()`) so I can order on the timeout, and I am independent of the system clock.

I use a one off `Sempahore` so the cancel thread gets started only once, and only when at least one task is executed.

In the `beforeExecute`, I queue a `TimedOutRunnable` instance, and in the `afterExecute`, I find it, and mark it finished (if still present)

On shutDown I need to interrupt the `cancelThread`.

The code on the cancel thread is fairly crazy, especially because of how it needs to deal with being interrupted. Before `shutDown` it needs to get the head of the queue and block if it's empty. Then after `shutDown` (marked by being interrupted) it needs to continue until the queue is empty, so no more blocking `take()` but `poll()` instead.

On interruption we also need to requeue the `TimedOutRunnable` we were sleeping for, as we'll need to still handle a possible cancel for it.

***Disclaimer*** : tested only superficially

```
public class TimedExecutorService2 extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    long timeout;

    public TimedExecutorService2(int numThreads, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {
        super(numThreads, numThreads, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1000));
        this.timeout = unit.toNanos(timeout);
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        super.execute(command);
    }

    private static class TimedOutRunnable implements Comparable<TimedOutRunnable> {

        private final Thread thread;
        private final Runnable runnable;
        private final long timeoutAt;
        private volatile boolean finished = false;

        TimedOutRunnable(Thread thread, Runnable runnable, long timeoutAt) {
            this.thread = thread;
            this.runnable = runnable;
            this.timeoutAt = timeoutAt;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(TimedOutRunnable o) {
            return Long.compare(timeoutAt, o.timeoutAt);
        }

        void cancel() {
            if (!finished) {
                thread.interrupt();
            }
        }

        void markFinished() {
            finished = true;
        }
    }

    private final PriorityBlockingQueue<TimedOutRunnable> timeoutQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>();
    private final Set<TimedOutRunnable> runningTasks = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());

    private final Thread cancelThread = new Thread(() -> {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            TimedOutRunnable timedOutRunnable = null;
            try {
                timedOutRunnable = timeoutQueue.take();
                long timeoutAt = timedOutRunnable.timeoutAt;
                long now = System.nanoTime();
                TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(timeoutAt - now);
                timedOutRunnable.cancel();
                runningTasks.remove(timedOutRunnable);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                timeoutQueue.add(timedOutRunnable); // requeue so we finish the timeout
            }
        }
        while (!timeoutQueue.isEmpty()) {
            TimedOutRunnable timedOutRunnable = null;
            try {
                timedOutRunnable = timeoutQueue.poll();
                if (timedOutRunnable != null) {
                    long timeoutAt = timedOutRunnable.timeoutAt;
                    long now = System.nanoTime();
                    TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(timeoutAt - now);
                    timedOutRunnable.cancel();
                    runningTasks.remove(timedOutRunnable);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // thread ends once we're done
                timeoutQueue.add(timedOutRunnable); // requeue so we finish the timeout
            }
        }
    });

    private final Semaphore startPermission = new Semaphore(1);

    @Override
    protected void beforeExecute(Thread thread, Runnable runnable) {
        if (startPermission.tryAcquire()) {
            cancelThread.setName("CancelThread");
            cancelThread.start();
        }
        TimedOutRunnable timedOutRunnable = new TimedOutRunnable(thread, runnable, System.nanoTime() + timeout);
        runningTasks.add(timedOutRunnable);
        timeoutQueue.add(timedOutRunnable);
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        Optional<TimedOutRunnable> found = runningTasks.stream()
                .filter(timedOutRunnable -> timedOutRunnable.runnable == r)
                .findAny();
        if (found.isPresent()) {
            TimedOutRunnable timedOutRunnable = found.get();
            timedOutRunnable.markFinished();
            runningTasks.remove(timedOutRunnable);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        if (!isShutdown()) {
            execute(cancelThread::interrupt);
        }
        super.shutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Runnable> shutdownNow() {
        if (!isShutdown()) {
            execute(cancelThread::interrupt);
        }
        return super.shutdownNow();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numThreads = 2, timeout = 7;
        ThreadPoolExecutor timedExecutor = new TimedExecutorService2(numThreads, timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            timedExecutor.execute(new Business(i));
        }
        timedExecutor.shutdown();

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please help to override this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have added the output too.

Comment: Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thank you much for your time. Still i am getting the java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted for few threads.My input scenario is   int numThreads = 2, timeout = 7; ||   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            timedExecutor.execute(new Business(i));
        }  ||  @Override
 public void run() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  try {
   Thread.sleep(5000);

Comment: Ah, yes, I found my race condition, when a task is complete, I look for it in the Queue, to mark it finished. But the cancel thread may be waiting for a task, and that task cannot be marked finished in this way. I'll need a separate collection of 'running tasks', I'll update my answer shortly.